# Sonata Admin search feature

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I recently updated my symfony2 project vendors. Thus I got latest Sonata Admin Bundle version (updated from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6).

I saw there is a new search feature in this release but I can't get it work. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Drives me crazy.

Here is my composer.json require :

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "1.3.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "knplabs/gaufrette": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3.*",

    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "2.1.*",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.0",
    "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "1.0.0",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "2.3.*",

    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.3.*@dev",
    "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle": "dev-master",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "v3.4.1",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "dev-master",
    "igorw/file-serve-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "zendframework/zendpdf": "2.0.*"
},
```

Right after the update I had the search feature complaining about a non existing block :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   block type sonata.admin.block.search_result does not exist") in
>   SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig at line 48

I corrected this one by declaring the block in my `config.yml`:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

But now, it is complaining about request not set :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   Request object has not been set") in
>   SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig at line 48

I really don't understand what I'm missing here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: clear your cache ...may be that will help...

Comment: I tried clearing my cache, didn't help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same error. 
It's probably because you are using the Request in an Admin.

```
$this->getRequest()->get('context', 'default')
```

The search does not set the request and the Admin triggers an exception if you are trying to get the request.

In my Admin, I am using a function to access the request parameter and avoid an exception.

```
public function getRequestParameterOrNull( $key, $default = null ){
    try{
        return $this->getRequest()->get($key, $default);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice catch, I have been stuck with this for a while now.

Comment: You might use `$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer(); if ($container->isScopeActive('request')) return $container->get('request');` inside your `catch`. This way you have a fallback because most of the time (if not all of the time) there is a request (your search).

Answer (score 20):

Add the block in your sonata block config:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list: #default sonata admin block
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts: [admin]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find below the full configuration:

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "v2.3.3",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/exporter" : "1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu":"1.1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master#da071a913b86619fdd35449713a53ffd4cde1f61",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "v0.3.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "0.*@dev",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
    "ibrows/newsletter-bundle": "dev-master",
    "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": ">=0.11,<0.13-dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "v2.0.5",
    "pasinter/admanager-bundle": "dev-master",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

I've just forced a specific commit for the sonata admin bundle, just to be sure that we are using the same version. I suggest to you to remove the `#da071a913b86619fdd35449713a53ffd4cde1f61` string from the configuration after the achievement of a working release.

**config.yml**

```
sonata_user:
    security_acl:     false
    class:
        user:         Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    profile:  # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
        form:
            type:               sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin Panel
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  AcmeAdminBundle:Default:standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig

        # search
        search:              SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        search_result_block: SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: ~

    templates:
        form:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
        filter:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

            show:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
```

Here the official documentation: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/search.html

Comment: I already added those lines to my config. So that's not the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but in your original question are not present, so I thought you've missed them :-)

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the full configuration. Hope this helps.